# Make strings blank based on boolean, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a model, `Photo`, that has two options, `is_photo` or `is_art`, each with their own separate fields.

But, when one option is chosen I want the other option's fields to be reset into blank strings.

This is what I have:

**photo.rb**

```
before_save :reset_photo_options
before_save :reset_art_options

def reset_photo_options
  if self.is_art == 1
    self.resolution = ""
    self.camera = ""
  end
end

def reset_art_options
  if self.is_photo == 1
    self.tool = ""
    self.medium = ""
  end
end
```

However, if I fill out the `is_photo` fields and then change to `is_art` and fill those out all of the fields are saved.

How can I successfully reset the other option's fields?

Comment: There may be some other interactions we don't have visibility into; setting them manually. Make sure the compares are actually firing. If `is_art` and `is_photo` are actual DB fields I'd revisit that choice (maybe even STI, which is fine for simple usecases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are proper boolean columns, at least as far as ActiveRecord is concerned, then you should be able to do this by using the `?` method variant that returns a strict `true` or `false` value:

```
def reset_photo_options
  return unless self.is_art?

  self.resolution = nil
  self.camera = nil
end

def reset_art_options
  return unless self.is_photo?

  self.tool = nil
  self.medium = nil
end
```

Setting as `nil` is usually better than as empty string since a NULL column is a clear communicator that the field is not relevant and not set. Empty string could indicate missing data or no user input captured.

A further refactoring of this is to describe which fields go with what type:

```
SPECIFIC_FIELDS = {
  art: [
    :resolution,
    :camera
  ],
  photo: [
    :tool,
    :medium
  ]
}

def mask_off_irrelvant_options
  SPECIFIC_FIELDS.each do |category, fields|
    next unless (self.send(:"is_#{category}?"))

    fields.each do |name|
      self[name] = nil
    end
  end
end
```

This presumes things can be art and photo at the same time. If that's not the case then you don't need a series of independent booleans, you need one category field.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with mutually exclusive options like this, I always create a single field that has the type.  With "enums" you can do something like this:

```
class Photo
  enum photo_style: [ :art, :photo ]
end
```

This gives you the ability to use similar methods:

```
photo.art?
```

that you would use with straight up booleans.

You can also use them in queries and such:

```
Photo.where(photo_style: :photo)
```

For your specific question, you can then roll the logic into a single callback:

```
before_save :reset_options

def reset_options
  if art?
    # do something
  elsif photo?
    # do something else
  end
end
```

More here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html